# How do I split a video into blocks using drawImage() in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, mp4, drawimage

I have a simple mp4 video file.

When I play it in HTML5, I want to split the the video into a 3x4 grid with each grid playing one portion of the video like this:

[image: Desired outcome]

However, my current code produces something like this:

[image: Current outcome]

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the drawImage() function but I don't know which part.

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>
      Lab 5: HTML5
    </title>
    <style>
      .box{
        width:660px;
        height:125px;
        margin-top: auto;
      }
      canvas{
        border:1px solid #fff;
        margin:10px 0 0 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="display:none">
      <video id="videoid" autoplay>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <canvas id="canvas00" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas01" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas02" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas03" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <canvas id="canvas10" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas11" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas12" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas13" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <canvas id="canvas20" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas21" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas22" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas23" width="160" height="120"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
      var ROWS = 3; // Number of rows
      var COLS = 4; // Number of columns
      var tile_array = new Array();

      for(var ri = 0; ri < ROWS; ri++) {
        for(var ci = 0; ci < COLS; ci++) {
          tile_array.push("tile"+ri+ci); // An array that stores id of tiles
        }
      }

      var video = document.getElementById("videoid"); // Get the video

      update(video); // Update video

      function update(video) {
        drawtiles(640, 360, ROWS, COLS, video); //
        setTimeout(function(){
          update(video)
        }, 33); // Update video every 33 miliseconds
      }

      function drawtiles(w, h, r, c, source) {
        var tileW = Math.round(w / c); // Get the width of a single tile
        var tileH = Math.round(h / r); // Get the height of a single tile

        for(var ri = 0; ri < r; ri++) {
          for(var ci = 0; ci < c; ci++) {
            var target_ri = parseInt(tile_array[ri*COLS+ci][4]);
            var target_ci = parseInt(tile_array[ri*COLS+ci][5]);
            var thecanvas = document.getElementById("canvas"+ri+ci);

            /*TO DO: implement the code for drawing the tile in the
            (target_ri, target_ci) position of the video, with width tileW
            and height tileH, onto this canvas in the (ri, ci) position of the web page*/

            var ctx = thecanvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(video, target_ri, target_ci, tileW, tileH);

          }
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-drawimage) for a good illustration of how the coordinates work (hint: your are missing 4 arguments.)

Comment: @H.B. I changed the function to "ctx.drawImage(video, target_ri, target_ci, tileW, tileH, 0, 0, 160, 120)". The dimension and resolution is where it should be now but the 12 blocks are still all identical (i.e. the block on top left corner). Does it have something to do with the sx and sy parameter?

Comment: Yes, if that is the case you are not getting the correct source portion of the image.

Answer (score 1):

`context.drawImage()` has 3 use cases depending on the number of arguments you provide. More accurately you have the following options:

```
context.drawImage(video, x, y);
```

which draws the frame at a specific `x,y` point on your canvas

```
context.drawImage(video, x, y, width, height);
```

which does the same, except that it shrinks/enlarges the video to the `width` and `height` properties you specify (if the video itself had a `600x800` resolution, and you specified `width = 300, height = 400` you would get the entire video frame shrunk down to those dimensions).

Your third option, which is what you are after is the following:

```
context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
```

This takes a specific rectangular region of the video frame, beginning at `sx, sy` and ending at `swidth, sheight`, and only draws that part at `x, y`.

If I understand your code correctly you should do the following:

```
videoX = video.width / c;
videoY = video.height / r;

ctx.drawImage(video, ci*videoX, ri*videoY, videoX, videoY, target_ri, target_ci, tileW, tileH);
```

Basically, the video has `width` and `height` properties of its own. You split the width in 4 parts (your columns) and the height in 3 parts (your rows). At `drawImage` you specify which part of the video frame you want to draw (2nd to 5th argument) and on which tile you want to draw it(last 4 arguments).

You can find more info on drawImage [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp).